# No configuration provided for scss file

Tags: npm, stylelint

When i try to `npm start`, error:

> No configuration provided for .../main.scss, Error in plugin
>   "gulp-stylelint".

Someone help me!

Comment: The correct link is https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The quickest way to add a configuration to Stylelint is [to extend](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/#extends) one of the officially shared config options:

- [stylelint-config-recommended](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-recommended)
- [stylelint-config-standard](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard)

You should extend the *standard* config if you want Stylelint to enforce stylistic conventions like spaces after colons in declarations, and use the *recommended* config if you don't.

To use the standard config, you should first install it as a `devDependency`:

```
npm install stylelint-config-standard --save-dev
```

Then create a configuration file, for example `.stylelintrc.json`, in the root of your project and add the following content to it:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard"
}
```